# React-Native-Camera Limit Camera Area

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have some problems limiting the Area of a RNCamera to its surrounding view.
All related tickets I found here did not provide a proper solution with RNCamera.

My Component has flex column design with two views.

- View 1: as a wrapper for the camera
- View 2: results view, colored in red with opacity

As you can see the RNCamera goes over the bounds of the surrounding view.
This leads causes problems while Barcode Scanning.

The barcode in the example screenshot is detected.

Is it possible to limit the react native camera to the bounds of its surrounding view?

Or if not is there a way to see the coordinates of the scanned barcode and compare it against the measurements of the Views.

The scanned barcode has bounds but I am not sure how to translate that to a proper position.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Bounds and position]

```
const Stocktake = () => {
    let redBoxView, cameraWrapperView, camera

    function onBarCodeRead(bc) {
        console.log('bc', bc)

        if (redBoxView) {
            redBoxView.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
                console.log('RedBox', x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
                console.log('X', pageX)
                console.log('Xend', pageX + width)
                console.log('Y', pageY)
                console.log('Yend', pageY + height)
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "purple", flex: 1 }}
                ref={view => {
                    cameraWrapperView = view
                }}>
                <RNCamera
                    ref={ref => {
                        camera = ref;
                    }}
                    defaultTouchToFocus
                    mirrorImage={false}
                    onBarCodeRead={(bc) => { onBarCodeRead(bc) }}
                    onFocusChanged={() => { }}
                    onZoomChanged={() => { }}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    playSoundOnCapture={true}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(254,0,0,0.6)", flex: 2, alignItems: "flex-end", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
                ref={ref => {
                    redBoxView = ref;
                }}>
                {redBoxView ? <Text>{JSON.stringify(redboxMeasures)}</Text> : null}
            </View>


        </View>
    );

}
```